# Can Azure Stream Analytics read Bond serialized events?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics, bond, stream-analytics

I am trying to to some POC using Azure Stream Analytics. I want to read from Azure Event Hub and store to Azure Blob Storage. I work with this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-real-time-fraud-detection).  The problem is that when I define my stream input (as my existing event hub) I see that stream analytics support only 3 serialization formats: JSON, Avro and CSV. My event serialization format is Bond and I cannot change that. Is there any way to still connect to Stream Analytics and define some conversion that it can apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Bond is not currently supported by Stream Analytics. You will need to convert your Bond messages into one of JSON, Avro, or CSV outside of Stream Analytics.